# PHP Regex only one space not at start or end of a string

Tags: regex

I have a Regex that accepts strings with spaces but not at the start or the end.
`(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])^(?!\s)(?![\s\S]*\s$)[a-zA-Z']{2,40}$`
I would like to make it allow one space only.
I changed it to `(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])^(?!\s)(?![\s\S]*\s$)[a-zA-Z'\s{0,1}]{2,40}$` but it is not working.
Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the string would only contain letters or spaces, we can try using a negative lookahead here:

```
^(?!\S* \S* )[A-Za-z ]+$
```

More generally, to allow up to only N spaces, but no more, we can write:

```
^(?!(?:\S* ){N+1})[A-Za-z ]+$
```

Comment: This works but it does not give you control on the number of spaces like \s{0,1}

Comment: `I would like to make it allow one space only` ... you should state your actual requirements up front.

Comment: Yes you are right sorry. I used brackets to be flexible :)

Comment: I updated my lookahead approach to be more generic.  Now you need only know how many spaces you want to whitelist.

Comment: This is prone to backtracking. `.*` should be changed to `\S*` or `[^ ]*`.